# Execute batchFile with command line argurment in silentmode

Tags: wix, custom-action

I want to execute my batchfile which takes 3 cmd line arguments in which it should execute silent mode[should not see the console].Below is my wix code:

```
    <CustomAction Id="ScrptsMngr" Property= "PrptyScrptsMngr"
              Value="&quot;[#filC22B3172A663C01F17B8CE4D55CB7DE2]&quot; [ARG1] [ARG2] [ARG3]" Execute="immediate"/>
               <CustomAction Id="PrptyScrptsMngr" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" Execute="deferred" Return="asyncWait" Impersonate="yes"/>
```

The above customaction action doesn't work for me. It always throws an error as CAQuietExec execution failed. Is my custom action is correct

Answer (score -1):

Try adding " (") for each ARG1/2/3 and try. Also make sure you have set the 'PrptyScrptsMngr' call after 'ScrptsMngr' in product.wxs seqeunce

```
<CustomAction Id="QtCmdLineRmDummies" Property="QtExecCmdLine"Value="&quot;[SystemFolder]cmd.exe&quot; /c del /Q &quot;[INSTALLLOCATION]\dummy*.*&quot;" />
<CustomAction Id="QtCmdRmDummies" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" Execute="immediate" Return="ignore" />
```

In product.wxs

```
<Custom Action="QtCmdLineRmDummies" After="InstallFinalize">NOT INSTALLED AND NOT REMOVE</Custom>
<Custom Action="QtCmdRmDummies" After="QtCmdLineRmDummies">NOT INSTALLED AND NOT REMOVE</Custom>
```

Comment: It doesn't works for me. May be i missed something. Here's is batch file content which takes 3 args and pass it to another batch file.

Comment: <CustomAction Id="ScrptsMngr" Property= "PrptyScrptsMngr"
                  Value="&quot;[SystemFolder]cmd.exe&quot; /c &quot;[#filC22B3172A663C01F17B8CE4D55CB7DE2]&quot;" Execute="immediate"/>
                   <CustomAction Id="PrptyScrptsMngr" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="yes"/>

Comment: as you said add " (") for each ARG1. could you tell how i need to pass in the customaction's Value?.